# What if someone says "I do?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A : Clay, I think you got something that belongs to me.
>
> B: I do?

What does "I do" signify here? Where should we use it?

*I interpreted it as: "Do I have?"*

Answer (score 1):

This dialogue is very informal and, in fact, not grammatically correct (but such everyday language is actually very common). "You got" is the Past Simple and if Clay's reply was a correct  [echo question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/questions-echo-and-checking-questions), then is would be "Did I?" But I believe speaker A means the following:

> A: I think you **have** got something that belongs to me.

We can use both "have got" and "have" talking about our possession in the present tense. So, Clay must have thought about it like *"I think you have got something that belongs to me."* And it would be understandable if Clay replied, "Do I?" But in this colloquial language moment, Clay went even further and said "I do?" instead.